# Run javascript as the form is being filled by users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am new to Google Apps Script and need help. I am trying to achieve the following:

Set a trigger for lost-focus of a textbox in Google Forms. The code in this event will be

1. Get the value of a textbox
2. Set the value of a textbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible with Google Apps Script and Google Forms.  Apps Script can be triggered by the submission of a Form, but it cannot interact with the Form in the users browser.

It is possible to build a form entirely in Apps Script (using HTML) which would allow you full control over the user experience, but you lose access to the functionality provided by Google Forms.

Comment: Link in the above comment points to a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Try Google Apps Script

- [Do more with add-ons and scripts](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308847?hl=en)
- [Overview of Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Option 2)
While adding arbitrary JavaScript is not supported by Google Forms,
it is still possible to get sources of your form, extend with extra scripts and host on your site with results still posted to Google Forms/Google Sheets

See

- [How to get JS script of a Google form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667384/how-to-get-js-script-of-a-google-form),
- [Google Forms + Google Sheets + Google Apps Script = ❤. Easy Database Solution for Static Websites](https://rohit-agrawal.medium.com/google-forms-google-sheets-google-apps-script-easy-database-solution-for-static-websites-38c817b94074)