# Auto fill answer in Google form through Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I'm trying to get some data from a Google sheet and fill a Google form field with it, which is actually an answer to a question.

Let's say, I have a sheet with two columns Name and Company.
The Form has two fields (questions) asking the same (Name and Company).

What I want is that the form should check for any Name in the Sheet which does not have a Company associated with it. It will check the first non-associated Name and write that Name in the answer of the form automatically. And leave the Company field to be filled manually by the user.

Is that possible with Google Scripts?

I have searched online for this, but have only found answers using "Pre-Fill Links" which does not help in my case. I will send only one link to all the users and not generate Pre-Fill links again and again.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't execute Google Apps Script on a Google Form that is being responded to. At all.

Comment: Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Make and serve your own HTML form. You can use a Google Form backend by programmatically submitting a response.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script - Run javascript as the form is being filled by users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977954/google-apps-script-run-javascript-as-the-form-is-being-filled-by-users)